# how to clean one dataset using another cell by cell

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset of count values at a series of locations following a continous calendar, see below:

| Date | LocationA | LocationB | LocationC | LocationD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 55 |
| 02/01/2000 | 4 | 0 | 15 | 52 |
| 03/01/2000 | 5 | 0 | 12 | 0 |
| 04/01/2000 | 3 | 0 | 1000 | 0 |
| 05/01/2000 | 8 | 0 | 12 | 53 |

I have a second dataset which informs whether the count is valid (y/n), see below:

| Date | LocationA | LocationC | LocationD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | n | y | y |
| 02/01/2000 | y | y | y |
| 03/01/2000 | y | y | n |
| 04/01/2000 | y | n | n |
| 05/01/2000 | y | y | y |

I need to parse the first dataset with the second to produce a cleaned version. Some locations are not listed in the 1st dataset that are in the 2nd and vice versa.
The output i need would like:

| Date | LocationA | LocationB | LocationC | LocationD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | N/A | N/A | 10 | 55 |
| 02/01/2000 | 4 | N/ A | 15 | 52 |
| 03/01/2000 | 5 | N/A | 12 | N/A |
| 04/01/2000 | 3 | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 05/01/2000 | 8 | N/A | 12 | 53 |

I have been able to do this in excel, but the dataset is too big and i cannot see how to do an example in R that has the same structure.

Answer (score 2):

We may create a logical matrix from 'df2' and use that to subset the data from 'df1' and assign it to `NA` in `base R`

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(df1)[-1], names(df2)[-1])
nm2 <- setdiff(names(df1)[-1], names(df2)[-1])
df1[nm1][df2[nm1] == "n"] <- NA
df1[nm2] <- NA
```

-output

```
> df1
        Date LocationA LocationB LocationC LocationD
1 01/01/2000        NA        NA        10        55
2 02/01/2000         4        NA        15        52
3 03/01/2000         5        NA        12        NA
4 04/01/2000         3        NA        NA        NA
5 05/01/2000         8        NA        12        53
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("01/01/2000", "02/01/2000", "03/01/2000", 
"04/01/2000", "05/01/2000"), LocationA = c(0L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 8L
), LocationB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), LocationC = c(10L, 15L, 
12L, 1000L, 12L), LocationD = c(55L, 52L, 0L, 0L, 53L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Date = c("01/01/2000", "02/01/2000", "03/01/2000", 
"04/01/2000", "05/01/2000"), LocationA = c("n", "y", "y", "y", 
"y"), LocationC = c("y", "y", "y", "n", "y"), LocationD = c("y", 
"y", "n", "n", "y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I think you should assing `NA` to all rows in variables from `df1` not present in `df`2`  so 
`LocationB` should be `NA` as the example from the OP. Nice answer by the way.

Comment: @JilberUrbina thanks, i didn't notice that earlier.